# How to get the current Virtual Key Code via WinUser.h?

Tags: c++, windows, key, virtual

I am using WinUser.h and need to know if there is a simple way of getting the virtual key of whatever key is pressed on the keyboard.

I have tried GetAsyncKeyState() and it works fine, but I need the actual virtual key to be returned rather than running through a long series of GetAsyncKeyState() calls to check every key on the keyboard.

I am essentially creating a system that allows users to map their controls, which is why it would be more ideal if I could get the virtual key and then run a check against keys that are not allowed.

Also, C++ is the language being used. Thank you for any help in this matter.

Comment: Why not use the prebuilt registry entry for this? There's one entry that maps keys. If you're set on doing it yourself, though, hooks give access to the VK code, whether it be a message hook for a window or a keyboard hook.

Comment: The message that tells you that a key is pressed, WM_KEYDOWN, always uses the virtual key code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly want to response to the WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP or (more likely) WM_CHAR messages. `WM_CHAR` give you the result after TranslateMessage does its job, so it's what you usually want. It'll give you both the translated virtual key code *and* the scan code of the key that was pressed, in case you need that as well.

Comment: So I looked over WM_KEYDOWN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and an example of its use here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#processing_keystrokes, but it does not actually return the value of the virtual key. Most of the system is already in place. The key is stored in the first byte of a DWORD within a save file for the user settings. I simply need to get the byte value of the virtual key so that I can pass it to a function that sets it into the specific DWORD.

Comment: Are you saying that when you receive the message, `wParam` doesn't contain the virtual key code?

Comment: Alright well, thank you for your help Jerry. This is a rather large and complex system and I really do not know where these messages are stored and can not figure out how to access the information at the moment. I will use your suggestions to look into it further, but worst case scenario I will just stick to my original implementation of calling GetAsyncKeyState() for each key that is allowed. That I know is working, I was just searching for a cleaner way of handling it.

Comment: @AndrewA.Ernst: Your code that handles WM_KEYDOWN receives a message (in the form of an `MSG` structure). You're just looking for the `wParam` member of that structure.